# Prove that $g(x)_n = f(x)_{n+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, generating-functions

Both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are generating functions in closed form. $f(x) = \frac{1-x^2}{1-x-x^2} $ and $ g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x-x^2} $.
Prove that $g(x)_n = f(x)_{n+1}$ for $n \ge 0$

How can I prove that? Can you guide me to the right path?

Comment: You can prove it by expanding both expressions to series.

Comment: You only need to check f(x)=xg(x)+1.

Comment: @Ennar do you mean to write them into their summation forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
\begin{align*}
    f(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_nx^n\\
    g(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty g_nx^n
\end{align*}
notice that
\begin{align*}
    f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}+1=xg(x)+1
\end{align*}
which implies
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_nx^n=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty g_{n}x^{n+1}
\end{align*}
so the corresponding coefficient for $x^n$ is equal, then we get $g_n=f_{n+1}, \ \forall \ n\ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the steps, I've got a question though, from where do we get $f(x) = xg(x) + 1$?

Comment: Just bring f(x) and g(x) into the equation to check. @ popcorn